# How to sync clock with chrony after every 1 minute

Tags: linux, raspbian, ntp

I want to sync my system clock with chrony after every 1 minute. The chrony.conf file says it sync after 11 minutes

Comment: Sure hope you read your NTP server’s ToS if you don’t run your own! Syncing that often is very unusual and heavily discouraged.

Comment: @DanielB I'm using a GPS receiver to sync time

Comment: Are you asking about the runtime clock or about the hardware clock? The 11 minute interval is only about saving the runtime clock to the hardware RTC, not about syncing it from NTP/GPS.